Please add Stack Snippets to SharePoint.SE
HTML, CSS, and JavaScript are heavily used in SharePoint development. It would benefit question-asking here if we could use runnable Stack Snippets in our code, especially when many SharePoint development questions with code are asked on Stack Overflow, but then users are pointed here if their question is closed.
For those unfamiliar, read about Stack Snippets here.

Although it seems helpful, my guess is that this feature will not serve the same purpose as in main SE site due to lack of SP context in code. Without it, it is kind a useless and won't properly display result as you would expect it in SharePoint environment.

Not all code shared on the site requires being run within the context of SharePoint to be useful or relevant. Much of it can run in its own context.

Not all, agree. My guess is that such code takes only very small % of all code shared. Also, such questions (without SP context) would fall into main SE site. Neverthess I support such feature and it would be nice, just think it will not be implemented.
